# SQL Server: Switch statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

in PHP and JavaScript you can use a Switch statement to avoid having multiple if / case statements.

Is there a way to achieve something similar in SQL so that for each case it runs a different Select ?
I would not need to cover a default case here, just a number of different case scenarios.

**PHP example:**

```
<?php
$myVariableInput;

switch ($myVariableInput) {
   case "input1":
     // do something
     break;
   case "input2":
     // do something different
     break;
   case "input3":
     // do again something different
     break;
}
?>
```

In my case I would like to have a number of cases and for each of them have a different Select, all within the same stored procedure.

Can someone here tell me if and how this could realised in SQL ?

Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `CASE` for simpler actions, or dynamic SQL for more complex query.

`CASE` can be used from within normal selects / views / table valued functions and would look like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x1=1 THEN (SELECT id FROM someTable) ELSE (SELECT id FROM otherTable)
```

For using dynamic SQL, you may define the SQL as string, possibly combining with CASE as well. Note this can be used only from within stored procedures:

```
DECLARE query VARCHAR(max)
SET query = 'SELECT * FROM ' + CASE WHEN @myVariableInput =  THEN 'Table1' ELSE 'Table2' END + ' WHERE some_condition='+@parameterForIt
EXEC sp_executeSql query
```

However, be aware that this is not usually the best practise, as the database will be confused with different execution plans for different tables. Best practice would be the one you defined in PHP, with different stored procedures for different cases:

```
switch ($myVariableInput) {
   case "input1":
     // execute StoredProcedure1
     break;
   case "input2":
     // execute StoredProcedure2
     break;
   case "input3":
     // execute StoredProcedure3
     break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. In my situation I will have around 50 cases with each of them requiring a different Select statement using the same table. Each of these Selects will be relatively small but all will have a different query structure. Would you suggest the above workflow in such a situation or something different ?

Comment: Optimal for execution would be having 50 stored procedures, but if the tables have less than billion entries, I think this is kind of an overkill. The dynamic SQL should work just fine for that. Or, if the queries are partially overlapping without aggregation, consider also defining one bigger query as a view (covering all situations if possible) and then do selects from the view.

Comment: Perfect - thanks very much. I'll try with the dynamic solution as the table will only contain several hundred records for the start.